# Program won't load in defined location

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble getting a program to open into my 2nd screen, here's what I have in relation to loading my form:

```
Imports DAL
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq

Public Class frmMain
  Public Property FormBounds As Rectangle

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        Dim x = 1280
        Dim y = 0

        'declare 2nd screen as default monitor to open program
        'set 1st screen as default if 2nd screen not detected
        Dim monitor = If(Screen.AllScreens.Where(Function(scr) Not scr.Primary).FirstOrDefault(), Screen.PrimaryScreen)

        Me.FormBounds = monitor
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.subErrLog("frmMain_Load", ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

For testing purposes, I placed my x and y coordinates in the code itself. But when testing on my laptop while connected to a monitor as secondary, both resolution being 1280*720, the program keeps loading into the 1st screen.

I've been raking my head at this issue for weeks now, but I still can't find the reason for this issue.

Comment: The code never assigns the x and y variables from the found monitor.

Comment: The `Bounds` property is the `Location` and `Size` combined. If you set the `Bounds`, there's no need or reason to set the `Location`.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as `workarea`. That should be `WorkingArea`.

Comment: Why use `Screen.AllScreens.Where(Function(scr) scr.Primary).First` when you can use `Screen.PrimaryScreen`? I would suggest `Dim monitor = If(Screen.AllScreens.Where(Function(scr) Not scr.Primary).FirstOrDefault(), Screen.PrimaryScreen)`. Does the lot in one line.

Comment: `workarea` was just a carry-over when I'm testing stuff. That nor `WorkingArea` autocapped for me so I don't think it works here?

Comment: *`workarea` nor `WorkingArea` didn't autocap for me. Correction